# Using INNER JOIN twice in the same query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm still trying to get the hang of SQL.  I built 1 query that pulls out thread_id's from a filter_thread(contains 'filter_id' and 'thread_id' columns) table and a filter('filter_id and 'tag') table'

Then, I use an entirely different query to find the thread table contents, which contains the 'thread_id.'

I realize this isn't the best way to do it, but can't get a successful query. Would anyone be able to help?

```
$query = "SELECT ft0.thread_id 
FROM filter f0 
INNER JOIN filter_thread ft0 ON ft0.filter_id = f0.filter_id 
WHERE f0.tag LIKE '%filter1%' 
OR f0.tag LIKE '%filter2%'"
$result = $query->result_array();
$thread = array();
foreach ($result as $thread_id)
{
   $id = $thread_id['thread_id'];
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM thread WHERE thread_id='$id'");
   $thisRow = $query->result_array();
   array_push($thread, $thisRow[0] );
}
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it in a single query, like so:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM filter AS f0
 INNER JOIN filter_thread AS ft0
    ON ft0.filter_id = f0.filter_id
 INNER JOIN thread AS t
    ON ft0.thread_id = t.thread_id
 WHERE f0.tag LIKE '%filter1%'
    OR f0.tag LIKE '%filter2%
```

Comment: works well. Thank you.  Only problem is some of the results are coming back duplicated.  I assume it happens if they share a duplicate phrase found in both filter1 and filter2.  Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: No, if you think that shouldn't happen, it's either because there are multiple records in the `filter_thread` table with the same `thread_id`, or multiple records in the `filter` table with the same `filter_id`. If these duplicate records are expected, but you don't want them in the result set, you might add a `DISTINCT` keyword to eliminate duplication (`SELECT DISTINCT t.* ...`)

Comment: thank you.  they are expected, and necessary for what I'm trying to do.  DISTINCT worked perfect.  love learning new things.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.x, t.y, ... from thread t
inner join filter f on f.thread_id = t.thread_id
inner join filter_thread ft on ft.filter_id = f.filter_id
where bla bla
```

With maybe some group by...?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT t.*, f0.*
FROM filter f0 
INNER JOIN filter_thread ft0 ON ft0.filter_id = f0.filter_id 
INNER JOIN thread t ON t.thread_id = ft0.thread_id 
WHERE f0.tag LIKE '%filter1%' 
OR f0.tag LIKE '%filter2%'"
GROUP BY f0.filter_id
```